# Linux Mint touchpad not working on dual boot with windows 10

Tags: linux-mint, windows

The touchpad is not working on Linux Mint. My touchscreen is working perfectly however. The computer is an Inspirion 13 7000 series, dual booting with Windows 10.

```
dmesg | grep mouse && dmesg | grep pad
[    0.833823] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.879432] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5664], y [..4704]
[    1.908791] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1276..], y [1148..]
[    1.965986] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800, board id: 3017, fw id: 1752976
[    1.965986] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800, board id: 3017, fw id: 1752976
king@king-Inspiron-7352 ~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue mentioned in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527793/clickpad-not-working-on-dell-inspiron-13-7000-running-ubuntu-14-04) as well, with a few potential solutions.

First, as described [here](https://trustdarkness.com/wordpress/dell-sputnik-xps-13-touchpad-settings-not-working-in-updated-ubuntumint/), try this:

```
1. Open /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf in your favorite text editor.
2. Add the line 'blacklist i2c-hid' (no quotes)
3. Save and reboot
```

The second possible solution is a lot more involved: compiling your own kernel. The first post [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=131433?f=42&t=131433) has steps on how to do that.